# Display Tweets In Readable Format In Tweepy

Tags: python, django

How can I make tweepy return actual tweets, I mean it should display tweets in human readable format?

I don't want it to return tweets like this:

```
   <tweepy.models.Status object at 0x95F1ABPo>
```

Codes

```
  def tweetstream(request):
        consumer_key=""
        consumer_secret=""
        access_token=""
        access_token_secret=""
        auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api=tweepy.API(auth)
        statuses=Cursor(api.list_timeline, owner='', slug='').pages()
        for status in statuses:
            print status
            return render_to_response('dash.html',{'statuses': statuses},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

tweepy.models.Status is just a class. It likely has fields you can use to access the contents of the tweet. Try `status.text`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

An API call returns the JSON of the call. Tweepy parses it into its own model known as Status. You can fetch different parameters of tweets and render them from this status model into django template.

Pass the whole 'statuses' as context to django template, and run them in a for loop there, and you can display stuff there like for displaying tweet, 'statuses.text'.

You can either use the twitter's standard template and render your tweets into or code your own html and display tweets in them as required.

Views.py:

```
def tweetstream(request):
        consumer_key=""
        consumer_secret=""
        access_token=""
        access_token_secret=""
        auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        api=tweepy.API(auth)
        statuses=Cursor(api.list_timeline, owner='', slug='').pages()
        context = {'statuses':statuses}
        return render(request, 'dash.html', context)
```

Render in Django template:

```
{% for tweets in statuses %}
tweets.text
{% endfor %}
```

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets

Answer (score 0):

Access the actual variable that contains the tweet (such as {{status.text}}) or define a **unicode** method on your Status model like so:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

That's assuming that Status is a Django model.

Comment: The Status is not a model in my django app. It was taken from tweepy's model. How can I go about that? I mean should I input it directly in tweepy's model?